# Flink CEP: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

> > flink run /home/admin/Documents/flink_cep/Flink-master/dist/Kinesis.jar

When I am trying to run Jar file in command line, getting error but my code is running fine in Netbeans IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NoSuchMethodError` indicates a version conflict.

You should verify that you compiled your Flink job with the same Flink version as your cluster is running.